# How to install Zed Attack Proxy in an Alpine container

Tags: linux, alpine-linux, owasp, zap

I have this `Dockerfile` which is an alpine image and I need to install `zaproxy`, I tried `RUN apk add zaproxy` but it gives the following error:

> ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM docker:18.09

RUN apk update

RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.21/terraform_0.12.21_linux_amd64.zip
RUN unzip terraform_0.12.21_linux_amd64.zip && rm terraform_0.12.21_linux_amd64.zip
RUN mv terraform /usr/bin/terraform

RUN apk add zaproxy
```

Is there a way I can download the binary and put it somewhere without using `apk` package manager?

Answer (score 1):

We have a variety of official ZAP ones as per https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/about/, the stable Docker file is https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile-stable

Comment: Can you give me the command to execute and ettack? Because when I try to use command line, it doesn't doesn't gives an empty output and when I try owasp zap gui it provides the outputs and vulnerabilities.

Comment: There are a variety of ways to run ZAP. You can run it inline from the command line using the options defined on https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/quick-start/cmdline/ so something like `./zap.sh -quickurl http://example.com/ -quickout /path/to/report.xml -quickprogress -cmd` However that limits what configuration details you can provide. You can also launch ZAP in daemon mode and then you get full control of it via the API. We also have packaged scans in the ZAP Docker images but they might not be so suitable for you. We also have an automation framework in development :)

Comment: Hi, thank you, I need to run this as a daemon and do some deep scannings. Can you guide me on how?

Comment: Not in a comment :D But we have lots of videos which cover that https://www.zaproxy.org/videos/ and full API docs https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#introduction For more info I'd recommending asking on the ZAP User Group https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Answer (score 0):

The official "bare" image uses alpine, check out the details here: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile-bare

In particular to specifically answer your question:

> Is there a way I can download the binary and put it somewhere without using apk package manager?

```
# Download and expand the latest stable release 
RUN curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zaproxy/zap-admin/master/ZapVersions.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v //url |grep -i Linux | wget --content-disposition -i - -O - | tar zxv && \
    mv ZAP*/* . &&  \
    rm -R ZAP*
```

As for actual use:

- [Getting Started Guide](https://www.zaproxy.org/getting-started/)
- [CLI Details](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/cmdline/)
- [API/Automation Docs](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/)

Comment: After installing how can I do a small attack? What is the command?

Comment: Usage info added to the answer.